# Get information about php

Tags: php

I just started with programing in PHP
And i have a problem:
I'm just experimenting and discovering the language. I tried compressing a string and display the output. I get an some zlib error. I am just wondering if there is a function that returns information about extensions?

Comment: If you have an error, show us the error. Also show us the code RELEVANT to where the error is happening

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick reply. I tried to get information about php with phpinfo(). I also searched for more similar errors and discovered that zlib has been disabled. Now everything works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use
`phpinfo();`
to display the PHP configuration.

Comment: I tried that and discovered that zlib was disabled